# Image format was not specified, Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove restrictions

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, qemu, nvme

I am trying to virtualize NVME based linux in QEMU on Windows using:

```
    qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2048 -cdrom ubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso -drive file=nvmeimage.img,if=
none,format=raw,id=D22 -device nvme,drive=D22,serial=1234
```

This gives the following error:

> WARNING: Image format was not specified for 'nvmeimage.img' and probing guessed raw. Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.
>
> Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.

Adding `format=raw` doesn't work.

Comment: This warning is not treated as an error in linux, so I installed ubuntu in another image file, and used it in linux installed in vmware to attach nvme device and it worked fine.